# How do I substitute the "-" with a minus sign without disaligning numbers in center enviorment

Tags: tables

I have a table made with booktabs with multiple values, some of which are negative. I want to substitute the "-" with an actual minus sign. I would also like the numbers to be centered without having the minus sign in consideration, avoiding these odd placements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Resumo dos resultados da atividade respiratória pelo complexo II através de um ensaio espetrofotométrico a \SI{600}{\nano\meter} com DCPIP}\label{tabelasss}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
Tempo (min) & B & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \midrule
0 & 0.000 & 0.031 & 0.139 & -0.018 \\
2 & 0.001 & 0.032 & 0.062 & -0.032 \\
5 & -0.001 & 0.031 & -0.008 & -0.040 \\
8 & -0.003 & 0.025 & -0.084 & -0.048 \\
10 & -0.004 & 0.023 & -0.130 & -0.052 \\
12 & -0.006 & 0.019 & -0.167 & -0.054 \\
15 & -0.008 & 0.014 & -0.221 & -0.058 \\
17 & -0.008 & 0.012 & -0.250 & -0.059 \\
20 & -0.010 & 0.006 & -0.289 & -0.061 \\
22 & -0.009 & 0.005 & -0.310 & -0.062 \\
25 & -0.010 & 0.003 & -0.335 & -0.060 \\
26 & -0.011 & 0.002 & -0.340 & -0.059 \\
27 & -0.010 & 0.002 & -0.340 & -0.061 \\
28 & -0.011 & 0.002 & -0.340 & -0.061 \\
30 & -0.013 & 0.000 & -0.340 & -0.058 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `S` column type from the `siunitx` package to properly align the numbers. This will also ensure that you actually get a minus sign instead of a hyphen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Resumo dos resultados da atividade respiratória pelo complexo II através de um ensaio espetrofotométrico a \SI{600}{\nano\meter} com DCPIP}\label{tabelasss}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{Tempo (min)} & {B} & {1} & {2} & {3} \\ \midrule
0 & 0.000 & 0.031 & 0.139 & -0.018 \\
2 & 0.001 & 0.032 & 0.062 & -0.032 \\
5 & -0.001 & 0.031 & -0.008 & -0.040 \\
8 & -0.003 & 0.025 & -0.084 & -0.048 \\
10 & -0.004 & 0.023 & -0.130 & -0.052 \\
12 & -0.006 & 0.019 & -0.167 & -0.054 \\
15 & -0.008 & 0.014 & -0.221 & -0.058 \\
17 & -0.008 & 0.012 & -0.250 & -0.059 \\
20 & -0.010 & 0.006 & -0.289 & -0.061 \\
22 & -0.009 & 0.005 & -0.310 & -0.062 \\
25 & -0.010 & 0.003 & -0.335 & -0.060 \\
26 & -0.011 & 0.002 & -0.340 & -0.059 \\
27 & -0.010 & 0.002 & -0.340 & -0.061 \\
28 & -0.011 & 0.002 & -0.340 & -0.061 \\
30 & -0.013 & 0.000 & -0.340 & -0.058 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The number format `table-format=-1.4` in the above code will mean

- space for a minus sign
- 1 digit before the decimal separator
- 3 digits after the decimal separator

[image]

Comment: Depending on your taste, you might want to also reserve the space for the minus sign in your 3rd column. This will make the columns equally spaced. As a downside, the gap before it will look larger...